# MPAndroidChart x labels date interval problem

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am implementing the function to display the change of exercise time by date as a graph.

I will briefly explain my code.

I processed the float data of the x label into string data.

ex) (float)200628 -> (string)20/06/28

But I have one problem.

The problem is that Difference between e.g. 2020-04-01 and 2020-04-02 is not the same as between 2020-03-31 and 2020-04-01

Due to this problem, my graph interval is not constant.

How should we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579206/mpandroidchart-x-date-value-duplication-problem), you should use another representation for the x values, e.g. "days since 1970":

```
val date = LocalDate.of(2018, 12, 31)
val x = date.toEpochDay()
```

See https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate#toEpochDay()

Thanks for accepting the answer if it solved your problem (also with your other question).